# aggregate items from subsites to root site (same content type)

Tags: 2013, list, office-365

On a SharePoint online (office 365) environment, assume you have three sub sites each containing a list (all lists contain same content type). Each sub site is made for a supplier. Suppliers use their sub sites to add items to the list. The root site contains a list which aggregates items from sub site's list. When suppliers go to root site they have read permission and must see only their one items that added to their sub site. Is it possible to solve it OOTB (no code at all)? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Content Query Web Part (CQWP) to solve this. It is available once you activate publishing features on your site. (or use a Publishing site)

You can make the following settings using the CQWP:

1. Select to display items from the entire Site Collection (Which
   will cover your 3 sub sites)
2. Select to display items belonging only to a specific Content Type
   (select your supplier Content Type here)
3. Use Audience Targeting setting of the CQWP to set the required
   permissions for the required groups.

Comment: Also content by search would be an alternative now that it has started to be rolled out in office 365 :)

Comment: True. I would use that if 1) I am not on a publishing site. 2) I am OK with the slight delay due to crawl time (compared to CSWP)

Comment: Thanks Vardhaman, I will test it and be back to mark your answr as answer.